# Moving from one Latitude and Longitude, to another point?

Tags: point, gps

I don't really have a good understanding of GPS other than I know what Latitude is and what Longitude is, but I don't know how exactly to move between the 2 points.

First  point is `Lat: 56.53515` and `Lng: -111.53155`
Second point is `Lat: 54.13513` and `Lng: -112.41244`

How can I move between the two points, at say `1.3 meters` per second?

This is for a program I'm working on, the 1.3m was just a random speed, and the coordinates were random as well. I would like to know how to calculate the distance between two points, so I can get the time it would take to travel that distance so I can increment / decrement the lat/lng at that speed until there.

Comment: Are you just trying to generate a list of points between those points at 1Hz? Tools? Programming language? What does GPS have to do with this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula

Comment: There are a number of similar questions here, which use the geodetic direct snd forwoard problems to calculate distance/bearing from two points, then calculate a new point from the first point with bearing and (fractional) distance. The parts you're missing are a programming framework, a code library the implents the geodetic problems, and your attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can identify these two locations using Google Maps, just by entering the coordinates like `(56.53515, -111.53155)` and `(54.13513, -112.41244)`

These show as being in Alberta Canada (the two stars in the map below).  Moving between the two may be slow at `1.3m/s` as the distance between the two is about 275km

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I don't know if I should have asked this in stack overflow because I'm using this for a project I'm currently working on, so unfortunately it isn't as easy as just looking it up on google and away we go :/

Comment: @Datsik please expand your question then, as it's unclear what you're actually wanting to do or how you intend on moving between the two points